# Cores in Boolean valued models

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra

The following is taken from Bell's *Set Theory: Boolean-Valued Models and Independence Proofs*. $V^{(B)}$ is a Boolean valued model, where $B$ is some (complete) Boolean algebra.

[image]

I'm stuck in verifying the second part of the  definition of a core. Namely, let $y\in V^{(B)}$ with $\|y\in u\|=1$. Pick $z\in w$ with $f_z=f_y$. This gives, by definition of $\|\cdot \in\cdot\|$,

$$1=\|y\in u\|=\bigvee \text{ran}(f_y)=\bigvee\text{ran}(f_z)=\|z\in u\|$$

Thus $\|z=x\|=1$ for some (unique) $x\in v$.  Ideally, I'd like to conclude that $\|x=y\|=1$, but I don't see why that holds. Expanding  the definition of $\|x=y\|$ does not seem very promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, here's one way of doing it:

> **Lemma**: *Say $x,y\in V^{(B)}$, with $f_x=f_y$. If $\|y\in u\|=1$, then $\|x=y\|=1$*.
>
> **Proof**:  Fix $z\in\text{dom}(u)$.The assumption $f_x=f_y$, says that $u(z)\wedge \|x=z\|=u(z)\wedge \|z=y\|$. Then
> $$
> \|x=y\|\ge \|x=z\|\wedge \|z=y\| \ge u(z)\wedge \|z=y\|
> $$
> Taking the supremum over $z\in\text{dom}(u)$,  we get that
> $$
> \|x=y\|\ge \bigvee_{z\in\text{dom}(u)}u(z)\wedge \|z=y\|=\|y\in u\|=1
> $$
> Therefore, $\|x=y\|=1$. $\square$.

Now assume $y\in V^{(B)}$ with $\|y\in u\|=1$. Pick $z\in w$ with $f_y=f_z$. We   have $\|z\in u\|=\|y\in  u\|=1$, so there exists (a unique) $x\in v$ with $\|z=x\|=1$. Note that
$$
\|x=y\|\ge \|x=z\|\wedge\|z=y\|=1\wedge 1=1
$$
by the lemma, so  $\|x=y\|=1$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Helps a lot because I am also stuck here:) Just a bit confused: why does "supremum=1" imply there is some $z$ s.t. $u(z)\land\parallel z=y\parallel>b$, since we are dealing with Boolean algebra but not a linear order? Actually the last two lines in your proof of lemma seems to show $\parallel x=y\parallel=1$ if we take supremum over $z\in$dom$(u)$.

Comment: @n901 You're absolutely right on both counts. Does it look good now? As you correctly observed, the two last lines of the proof of the lemma do what we want. Thanks for letting me know of the problem, I'm glad the argument could be salvaged (I remember this passage in the book being extremely frustrating).

Comment: Yes it looks perfect now.