# Question on Replacement axiom in Boolean valued models

Tags: logic, set-theory

Question on the use of the replacement axiom in Lemma 1.31. in John Bells' (2011) Boolean valued models and Independence proofs (p.37).

In the proof of the mentioned lemma, Bell argues as follows:

Fix a $u \in V^{(B)}$. Then define for any $x \in  V^{(B)}$: $f_x= \{\langle z, u(z) \wedge [[x=z]]\rangle: \mbox{for any z} \in dom(u) \} $. Using the axiom of replacement we can find a set $w\subseteq V^{(B)}$ such that for each
$x \in V^{(B)}$ there is $y \in w$ for which $f_x = f_y$.

Also, Bell uses this formulation of the axiom of replacement:

$\forall u ( \forall x \in u  \exists y  \varphi(x,y) \rightarrow ( \exists w \forall x \in u \exists y \in w \varphi(x,y) )   )$

My question is the following: Shouldnt Bell argue that we can find a set a set $w\subseteq V^{(B)}$ such that for each
$\mathbf{x \in dom(u)}$ there is $y \in w$ for which $f_x = f_y$. Or is the use of replacement by Bell  correct in the argument above?

Comment: I believe you can simply use the axiom scheme of comprehension here since for all $x\in V^B$ you have that $f_x:\text{dom}(u)\rightarrow B$ and the functions from $dom(u)$ which is a set, to $B$ which is also a set is a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering only names in the domain of $u$ is probably not enough. If $x,y$ both belong to $u$ with probability $1$, and $z$ is a mixing of $x,y$, then $z$ also belongs to $u$ with probability $1$, and it may not be equivalent to anything in the domain of $u$.

This is how Bell uses replacement here (actually this form is usually called axiom of collection). For any $x\in V^{(B)}$, $f_x$ is a function from $\text{dom}(u)$ to $B$. Let $F=\{f_x:x\in V^{(B)}\}$; this is a set by comprehension. Now for each $f\in F$, there exists $x$ such that $f=f_x$, and we apply replacement.

You may be interested in this post which discusses the same lemma: [Cores in Boolean valued models](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347903/cores-in-boolean-valued-models?rq=1)

Comment: Can you please explain how that $F$ is a set follows from comprehension?

Comment: @MadHatter the collection of all functions $f:\text{dom}(u)\rightarrow B$ is a set, and $F$ is the subset consisting of all $f$ such that $f=f_x$ for some $x\in V^{(B)}$.

Comment: Thank you. As I understand it,  you also must use replacement to define every $f_x$, so the axiom is applied at two different places of the lemma.

Comment: @MadHatter You don't use replacement twice. Rather you do use comprehension twice. First write down a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ that expresses $y=f_x$, namely "$y$ is the subset of $\text{dom}(u)\times B$ consisting of..." $\forall x\exists y\varphi(x,y)$ is proven by comprehension. Now define $F$ as above, using comprehension again. Next you use replacement/collection with domain $F$.